# Event capturing and bubbling phases are REVERSED on the node that fires the event

Tags: javascript, events

**Update: I'm using Chrome, in Safari everything works as expected.** 
Long story short. I was thinking I know js pretty good. Decided to take a test to please my ego and BOOM:

We have `<input type="button" id="btn">` and we add two event handlers to it.

```
addEventListener('click', handler1, false);
addEventListener('click', handler2, true);
```

**Question**: what handler will be executed first?

**Me**: Easy, handler2 is working in **capturing** phase and will be executed first.

**Reality**: execution order: `handler1` and then `handler2`

So it seems that for the node that fires the event we have bubbling phase that goes first, and then capturing phase.

In other words **capturing** phase **ends** **AFTER** **bubbling** phase **starts**.

This is contrary to the picture we all imagine when thinking about capturing and bubbling:
[image]

It seems that in reality this picture should look something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know/have any explanation of this?

Snippet:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#btn');


function handler1(e){alert("Hi from handler1, phase: Bubbling")};
function handler2(e){alert("Hi from handler2, phase: Capturing")};

input.addEventListener('click', handler1, false);
input.addEventListener('click', handler2, true);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="I'm clickable button"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow

Looking at the value of "eventPhase", you can see it is actually at the "target" phase.  When at the target, it doesn't matter what you use for the capturing value, because it is neither capture nor bubbling phase.  The handlers get called in the order that they are attached.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#btn');

//e.eventPhase: 1=Capture 2=Target 3=Bubbling
handler = (capture,e) => console.log(`eventPhase: ${e.eventPhase},`,`phase ${capture}`);
function handler1(e){console.log(`eventPhase: ${e.eventPhase},`,"Hi from handler1, phase: Bubbling")};
function handler2(e){console.log(`eventPhase: ${e.eventPhase},`,"Hi from handler2, phase: Capturing")};

input.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(null,'doesnt matter1'), !!Math.round(Math.random()));
input.addEventListener('click', handler1, false);
input.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(null,'doesnt matter2'), !!Math.round(Math.random()));
input.addEventListener('click', handler2, true);
input.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(null,'doesnt matter3'), !!Math.round(Math.random()));

document.body.addEventListener('click',handler.bind(null,'Bubbling'),false);
document.body.addEventListener('click',handler.bind(null,'Capturing'),true);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="I'm clickable button"/>
```